# How to change default date format of Oledb adapter to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, date, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I am using following function in my code,to read excel input but one of the column from excel is CreateDate at that point it is not accepting `MM/dd/yyyy` date format.
 Please suggest me appropriate changes to do the same.
Thanks in advance.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
 {
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dtsheet =conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,null);
    string ExcelSheetName = dtsheet.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();
    // "Excel file read"
    string sheet = @"SELECT Format([create date],   FROM [" + ExcelSheetName + "]"; 
    using (OleDbDataAdapter ad = new OleDbDataAdapter(connStr, conn))
       {
            ad.Fill(dt);
       }
            conn.Close();
 }
```